# Enable to handle an element in html-5 using protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I newbie to protractor and my requirement is automating third party tools.
I was unable to detect an web element, the functionality of element is on click it changes its state and pulls data from other application it is changing its class value

FROM

```
 ui-select-container ui-select-multiple select2 select2-container select2-container-multi ng-empty ng-valid ng-touched
```

TO

```
 ui-select-container ui-select-multiple select2 select2-container select2-container-multi ng-empty ng-valid ng-touched select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open open
```

I am curious about the tag:

```
'select2-container-disabled
```

In what way it can affect my code?
I have tried to find the element using xpath & ng attribute but was unable to detect element and i found

```
ng-disabled="$select.disabled"
```

I tried css,xpath and input tag source code.
Can you please suggest me how to deal with this element?

If the element is disabled can i handle that element using some code in protractor

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: Can you share your html snippet ?

Comment: I don't see `select2-container-disabled` in either of those code snippets

Answer (score 0):

If it's disabled then it's not clickable. the `isElementClickable` function is mostly testing for whether an element is enabled or not.

You can maybe scrape data from it though